# Does the W boson in beta decay affect the gravity generated by the system?

Tags: radiation

During beta decay we now know a heavy W boson gets involved temporarily. Would this potentially impact the gravitational field generated by the system as a whole? It doesn't seem like it should. Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest mass of the intermediate particle is not relevant. Even if the W boson was real and not only a virtual particle, the energy-momentum is conserved during beta decay and the whole energy-momentum couples to the gravitational field in the Einstein equations
$$
G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}
$$
where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor. So the W boson does not influence the gravitational field.